# Is Casey the killer and she is the one who was "split"

Tags: split

I thought Casey was the actual killer and "Split" and that Dennis, Kevin and the others were manifestations of her and that she was the killer.

Here are the clues: Kevin was not  caught, Her uncle animal in the woods told her animals don't wear clothes with her there like a monster, and Kevin or Dennis in one of his personalities liked to watch naked little girls dance, there is very little conversation if any AND a "split screen" when the 3 girls are first together after they were kidnapped and brought in the first room.

Also that would explain why it appeared that Dennis didn't notice her when she got in the car. Also same shot gun and she knew which locker had the gun and the ammo at the end.

**Would love to know what the writer and the producer were thinking on those lines**

Comment: related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71949/how-is-caseys-history-related-to-movie/71952#71952

Answer (score 5):

## No.

Casey is seen in multiple different scenes as just a girl.

- By the other girls parents in the mall
- By the other girls when talking
- By the police at the end

Not only that, but Kevin is also seen in multiple different scenes as an actual man.

- By the security tapes with Shyamalan's cameo
- By his therapist
- By all the zoo staff

If Casey and Kevin were the same, and all the scenes during the movie were just personality points of views, scenes where both of them and the other girls appear wouldn't make sense, and someone at the zoo would've recognized them as she left her cage at the end.

His character [was actually written years ago](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/m-night-shyamalan-split/), when [Unbreakable](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217869/?ref_=nv_sr_2) came out.

> I wrote this character [Kevin] and a bunch of the scenes you saw in the movie for the Unbreakable script. He was the original antagonist and David Dunn was going to meet him in the original script.